# How can i meet two uneven ends of plaster on ceiling?

Tags: plaster

Remodeling my new home and took a wall out. Plaster was different thickness on different sides of the wall sometimes up to 3/8s. How do I patch it nice and even, is it even possible? Should I drywall and hire a plaster guy to plaster over drywall? What solutions do you recommend? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Which side is thinner? If it's the inside, I'd try to shim it out. If the inside is thicker, you could just tear out that little section and fill it back in with drywall until it's close enough to fix with mud / plaster

Comment: I agree with cutrightjm, except I'd rip the interior out completely anyway, and start fresh with new plaster. Drywall is too rigid of a system, to match up easily. With plaster, you can use the other surfaces to "screed" the green coat out.

Answer (score 1):

I like cutrightjim's suggestion of replacing the interior portion of the ceiling board. You could completely eliminate the primary problem this way.

Otherwise, 3/8" is nothing to a good taper (or an amateur with patience), as long as you have room to work it out. You do. You'll need a wide knife or trowel, though. 24" minimum.

Fill the void with drywall to the level of the lower plane (higher with respect to the floor). Skim between the planes to pre-fill, and allow this to dry completely. It might take several days. It should be completely white throughout.

Now tape both sides of the channel as normal. Once that's dry, start leveling. Apply compound from the edge of the higher plane outward, as wide as your trowel. Again, let that dry thoroughly. Again, it might take several days.

Continue that process, using the low edge and the contact point of your trowel as screed guides. Finish by skimming the whole area, tapering gradually over 32" or more. Only light sanding should be needed if you've done a good job.

Answer (score 0):

However, smooth plastering well is difficult, and takes a lot of skill to get good at. I wouldn't recommend an overhead project as your first attempt; thus, if you want that smooth finish, you might as well just stop now and hire a professional.

Alternatively, if you don't mind switching to a textured (like orange peel, or popcorn) ceiling, it will make it a lot easier to cover up changes in height / your mistakes.

Corners are the hardest part of doing a ceiling, so you'll want to leave that hallway area intact.

As Curtrightjm commented, if the section with the adjustable light is higher than the hallway, just rip it out, and install drywall of matching depth.  If it is lower than the hallway you can just shim the area that had the wall with pieces of drywall that are the same height as the adjustable light, then layer over with the entire low patch with 1/4 drywall, feather it out, then texture / plaster.

Comment: I disagree that texture would hide a dramatic plane shift. Side light (which ceilings usually have) will clearly show it. Texture doesn't hide much aside from other texture, in my experience.